# Django one to many relationship for API call in restframework using serializers

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I have two models which are question and set of choices aligned with that question. I want to combine these two models to create an API which shows a list of question with their choices.

These are my models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField("date published")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text


class Choice(models.Model):
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

These are my serializers

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('question_text',)


class ChoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = ('choice_text','question',)


class QuestionWithAnswer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    question = QuestionSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = ('question',)
```

And this is the view class

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', ])
def getquestionWithChoices(request):
    question = Question.objects.all()
    serializer = QuestionWithAnswer
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

I have tried many things but could not get the below output.

```
  [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "question_text": "What's your name?",
            "pub_date": "2019-04-13T05:27:21Z",
            "choices": [
              {
                "id": 1,
                "choice_text": "fred",
                "votes": 0,
                "question": 1
              },
              {
                "id": 2,
                "choice_text": "bob",
                "votes": 0,
                "question": 1
              },
              {
                "id": 3,
                "choice_text": "rachel",
                "votes": 0,
                "question": 1
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "question_text": "What's your age?",
            "pub_date": "2019-04-13T05:27:39Z",
            "choices": [
              {
                "id": 4,
                "choice_text": "15",
                "votes": 4,
                "question": 2
              },
              {
                "id": 5,
                "choice_text": "16",
                "votes": 2,
                "question": 2
              },
              {
                "id": 6,
                "choice_text": "17",
                "votes": 2,
                "question": 2
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my view :

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', ])
def getquestionWithChoices(request):
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    serializer = QuestionWithAnswer(questions, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

This is my serializer:

```
class ChoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = ('id', 'votes', 'choice_text',)


class QuestionWithAnswer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    question = ChoiceSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('id', 'question_text', 'pub_date','question')
```

Here is my model:

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question,  related_name='question', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Anyone looking for same can use this.All remaining code is same as question.

Comment: Can you please tell me .How database fields  value should i inserted. Manually @Simal

Answer (score 1):

You are not instantiating the serializator correctly.

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', ])
def getquestionWithChoices(request):
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    serializer = QuestionWithAnswer(questions, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

and your serializers are not correctly defined also:

```
class ChoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = ('id', 'votes', 'choice_text','question',)


class QuestionWithAnswer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choices = ChoiceSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('id', 'question_text', 'pub_date', 'choices')
```

Comment: I am getting below error after your suggested edit : AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `choices` on serializer `QuestionWithAnswer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Question` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Question' object has no attribute 'choices'.

Comment: Thanks for the help.I missed one more parameter  : related_name='question' in Choice model. Please people looking for the answer can add : question = models.ForeignKey(Question,  related_name='question', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Comment: thanks for help.Sorry I can't upvote your answer due to my low points.Surely I will do once I get my points.